# How to enable sample based profiling of Android on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have Eclipse Juno with ADT plugin installed.

When I try to profile my Android game in DDMS perspective, I see that there is no option to do sample based profiling.

My profiling results are skewed toward methods that have more number of calls and hence aren't giving me true CPU time hogging methods.

I even updated my ADT as per http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html.

But I don't have the option of sample based profiling. It appears to be doing full method tracing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that sample based profiling is available in later versions of Android (Kitkat and up I think, but I'm not sure). I was trying it on Jellybean and that's why I got no option.

So the device on which you're running the game for profiling should be running the required Android version.